# Optimization of a function using Apache Commons Math

Tags: optimization

I tried solving the following problem using the SuanShu optimization library, with no success.

The optimization problem is:

Find the largest integral h such that the following constraint holds:

```
(h-2) * ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficient(b+h-2, h-1) -
        ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficient(b+h-3, h-3) +
        ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficientDouble(b+h-3,h-2)
        - 2*epsilon*N
```

where b,epsilon, N are given and they are int, double, int respectively.

Can you please tell me which optimizer I should use and what optimization function ?

The code up to now looks like this:

```
    public void optimize(){
            //create the univariate function to be optimized
    UnivariateRealFunction functionToOptimize = new UnivariateRealFunction() {

        @Override
        public double evaluate(double h) {
            return -h;
        }
    };
    UnivariateRealFunction hConstraint = new UnivariateRealFunction() {

        public double evaluate(double h) {
                          (h-2) * ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficient(b+h-2, h-1) -
                                  ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficient(b+h-3, h-3) +
                                  ArithmeticUtils.binomialCoefficientDouble(b+h-3,h-2)
                                  - 2*epsilon*N
        }
    };

    List<RealScalarFunction> constraints = new ArrayList<RealScalarFunction>();
    constraints.add(hConstraint);

    ConstrainedOptimProblem problem = new ConstrainedOptimProblem(
            functionToOptimize, 
            null, 
            new GeneralLessThanConstraints(constraints));

    BFGS bfgs = new BFGS();

    PenaltyMethodMinimizer optim = new PenaltyMethodMinimizer(
            PenaltyMethodMinimizer.DEFAULT_PENALTY_FUNCTION_FACTORY, 
            1e30,
            bfgs);

    optim.solve(problem,1e-3,200);

    Vector xmin = optim.search(new DenseVector(new int[]{8}));
    double fxmin = functionToOptimize.evaluate(xmin.get(1));    
    System.out.println("fxmin: "+fxmin);
    System.out.println(String.format("f(%s) = %f",
            DoubleUtils.doubleArray2StringArray(xmin.toArray()), fxmin));

    }
```

I took a look at the Apache commons math library and I don't have a clue on how to use it for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SuanShu, you can try the [brute force minimizer](https://nm.dev/html/javadoc/nmdev/dev/nm/solver/multivariate/constrained/integer/bruteforce/BruteForceIPMinimizer.html) or [DeOptim](https://nm.dev/html/javadoc/nmdev/dev/nm/solver/multivariate/geneticalgorithm/minimizer/deoptim/DEOptim.html). For DeOptim, you need to code up your integral constraint cell factory, such as this: IntegralCellFactory.java

Comment: Ok, I used brute force minimizer. Out of curiosity, when I used the Penalty minimizer the results where absolutely wrong. I assume it gets stuck in a local minimum. The question is why does that happen and don't minimizers have a protection mechanism against that ? I'm aware of the MultiStartOptimizer, but I'm referring to other mechanisms.

Comment: All Penalty minimizer does is to convert a unconstrained problem into a constrained problem by adding a huge penalty to constraints. Then it runs any unconstrained optimizer you like. There is no guarantee that the constraints are not even violated. The "made" up unconstrained objective function can be ugly (non-convex, jumps, you name it...) so, yeah, it can easily get stuck in a local.

Each minimizer class should be kept minimal. If we want to have some sort of protection, it should be "added" or "coded" outside the minimizer class. Otherwise, we would need to repeat the same mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up the idea of using Apache commons mainly because it's not very useful for optimization problems with non linear constraints. 
I used the brute force minimizer and it did the job.